# Confusion regarding surjective function

Tags: functions

I am a high school student, today our teacher taught us about onto function, explain only thing that I understand 
What I have understand -- that is two values of $x$ have same value of $y$ mean $y=1$ is a onto function but how find the function is onto for the given different equations.

Edit - i have one more doubt regarding the same function
what my teacher told me that for every value of x there is value in set y am if i am right suppose set x contain 4 element and set y contain 3 element one one function is not possible if my above statement is right please correct me if i am wrong

Is parabola is always a onto function

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Are you confusing injective with surjective?

Comment: Yes little a bit because it  injective function say function is one one that is function is not onto ,what my teacher told me that for every value of x  there is value in set y am if  i am right suppose set x contain 4 element and set y contain 3 element one one function is not possible if my above statement is right

Comment: You really need to learn to use punctuation. Your texts are extremely hard to read, because they just run on.

Comment: Sorry i improving my grammar as well as my english hopefully in future i will improve it if you can clear my edit doubt.

Answer (score 2):

Surjective is another word for onto.

A function $$f:A\to B$$ is onto if for every $y\in B$ the exists at least one $x\in A$ such that $f(x)=y$

For example $f(x)=x^2$ is an onto function from $(-\infty, \infty) $ onto $[0, \infty)$

Because for every non negative real number $y$ we have $f(\sqrt x)=y$

Comment: Sir given function should be onto from minus infinity to infinity why you have written from 0 to infinity because not two value from 0 to infinity have same value of y

Comment: Squaring only yields non-zero real numbers, such that the function cannot be onto if you allow negative real numbers in your codomain.

Comment: The codomain is $[0,\infty)$ which makes the function onto. If you expand the codomain to the whole real line then it is not onto. In any case the function is not one to one.

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you can understand this picture, then you can understand why a function from a set of four elements to a set of 3 elements cannot possibly be one-to-one (i.e injective).

https://img.yumpu.com/35419243/1/500x640/non-regular-languages-pigeonhole-principle-the-pigeonhole-.jpg

**

If you can understand these pictures, I think you will understand the definition of one-to-one (injective) functions, onto (surjective) functions, etc..

https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/images/function-mapping.svg

**

Also, a remark to the other people who posted: I answered this question because I think it is quite mean for people to downvote a highschool student's sincere question. If you do not like the grammar, edit it rather than downvoting.

Comment: Sir if you can provide me the way through i can find the functions to be onto

Comment: you need to take an arbitrary element of the range, and show that there is something in the domain that goes there. For example, consider the function $f:{0,1,2} -> {100,101}$ given by $f(0) = f(1) = 100$ and $f(2) = 101$. If we want to show $f$ is onto then, we need to find something which goes to 100 and something that goes to $101$. Since $f(1) = 100$, $1$ goes to $100$. Since $f(2) = 101$, $2$ goes to $101$. That is all! So $f$ is onto - it is simple! Try showing for yourself that $f(x) = x^3$ is onto as a function from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: (and note that the example $f(x) = x^2$ has been explained in the other answer)

Comment: I have an example The mapping f:R→R defined by f(x)=x3+1 is injective.

Proof. Let x1,x2∈R and suppose f(x1)=f(x2). Then
f(x1)=f(x2)x31+1=x32+1x31=x3 x1=x2 mean there are two element in set A let say x1,x2 who have common y value and if x1 not equal x2 then function will be onto am i right sir

Comment: you are right that $f(x) = x^3 + 1$ is injective. It is also onto but you have not proved that. But your proof for injectivity looks correct. you set $x_1^3 + 1 = x_2^3 + 1$ and then subtracted $1$ from both sides to get $x_1^3 = x_2^3$ and then took cube roots to get $x_1 = x_2$, which proves injectivity, so good job!